# Flutter: call function in background or just kill the background process

Tags: android, flutter, terminate, isolation

I've been looking everywhere about how to call a function in background (from main isolated process / foreground), but there's no result so far.

This is roughly the process I'm talking about:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(myBackgroundMessageHandler);

    runApp(MyApp());
}

Future<void> myBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        "Title",
        "Body",
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            "channelid",
            "none",
            "none",
            priority: Priority.high,
          ),
        )
    );
    audioPlayer = await audioPlayerCache.loop("ring.mp3", isNotification: true);
}

void stopRing() async {
    await audioPlayer.stop();
}
```

When the **audioPlayer** is called in background, calling **stopRing()** function from foreground will NOT affect anything because - *I think* - they are in different isolated process.

Here is the flow: app receive firebase notification (in **background**) -> show notification (using flutter_local_notifications plugin) and play sound -> user tap the notification -> wakeup the app -> call stopRing() (**not working**, the app is already in **foreground**).

So, my question is, how to call stopRing() in background from foreground process, or probably just simply terminate the background process, I guess that will stop the ring, too.

Thanks in advance...

*(Note: everything else is working well, except the problem mentioned in this post)*

Answer (score 0):

I was also implementing the exact feature you mentioned, and facing the same challenge. I managed to solve it using `IsolateNameServer` to communicate with isolated process.

---

In your background process, setup listener to stop the audio player as below:

```
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';

Future<void> myBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        "Title",
        "Body",
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            "channelid",
            "none",
            "none",
            priority: Priority.high,
          ),
        )
    );


    final SendPort? sendStopBeep = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('stop_beep_send_port');
    if (sendStopBeep == null) {
        ReceivePort portStopBeep = ReceivePort();
        IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(portStopBeep.sendPort, 'stop_beep_send_port');
        
        portStopBeep.listen((dynamic data) {
            // You should stop the audio player here
            await audioPlayer.stop();
            IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('stop_beep_send_port');
        });

        // You should start the audio player here
        audioPlayer = await audioPlayerCache.loop("ring.mp3", isNotification: true);
    }
}
```

---

When your app state resumes (or wakes your app), trigger the stop audio player event to the above port listener:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
        if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
            final SendPort? send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('stop_beep_send_port');
            if (send != null) {
                send.send(['test', 1]); // You can send any object over, ['test', 1] is just an example
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps!